# Model without using sql

Tags: machine-learning

Is there any model /approach to build question answer model for tabular data without using sql. I don't want sql come into picture anytime. I have tested couple of models but no luck

Comment: Q/A models and SQL are not linked: You can use txt/csv files but cannot process them in parallel by several users.

Comment: Hi @Abhi, welcome to the site. It is not clear what you are asking. Please, clarify what you understand by "question answer model" and describe which models you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can construct a qna system. For starters, you can look into [rasa](https://rasa.com/). It is an open-source conversational ai platform. If you have some bucks to spend, you could try out [azure's qna maker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/cognitive-services/qnamaker/transparency-note-qnamaker#introduction-to-qna-maker).